# Why file don't upload on site on python requests

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests, upload

I wand upload file on site: https://www.pdfyeah.com/remove-pdf-metadata/

Here my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.pdfyeah.com/remove-pdf-metadata/'
files = {'upfile': open('1.pdf', 'rb')}
session = requests.session()
session.get(url)
r = session.post(url, files=files)
search = r.text.find("Completed")
print(r.text+"\n")
print(search)
```

But i dont see "Congratulatin ... Dowload"
Here data from HTTP Sniffer Analizer

```
Request Headers            Value                                                                                                                                 
(Request-Line)             POST /remove-pdf-metadata/ HTTP/1.1                                                                                                   
Host                       www.pdfyeah.com                                                                                                                       
Connection                 keep-alive                                                                                                                            
Cache-Control              max-age=0                                                                                                                             
Origin                     https://www.pdfyeah.com                                                                                                               
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests  1                                                                                                                                     
DNT                        1                                                                                                                                     
Content-Type               multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDPrq1DWNDyvsBWne                                                                  
User-Agent                 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.4.3991.125 Safari/537.36                                
Accept                     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8                                                 
Referer                    https://www.pdfyeah.com/remove-pdf-metadata/                                                                                          
Accept-Language            ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7                                                                                                   
Cookie                     __gads=ID=353fb459c43c75d6-22c36bbad1b90081:T=1611821476:RT=1611821476:S=ALNI_MZPzMrxLT3iuoyEGWQuNFwlOUZ1zg; cookiebanner-accepted=1  
Accept-Encoding            gzip, deflate                                                                                                                         
Content-Length             249873
```

Here post data:
[image]

Where mistake in my code? Thanks...

Comment: Use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) to get it working.

Comment: i know about selenium, maybe i can make this any another way?